# Is there a way to create a direct link to Isotope filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope to filter our portfolio section by category. Is it possible to create an URL that will link to directly to a filter? Currently the URL is http://new-had.herrmanneasyeditdemo.com/#filter for every category.

I want to link directly to the law firm filter which is under the Industry drop down menu. Is this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

http://new-had.herrmanneasyeditdemo.com/#work

Comment: First of all, set the hashtag to something unique for each filter. Then just listen to hashtag changes, and filter based on the hashtag value.

Comment: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/hash-history-jquery-bbq.html (Although this is the v1 docs, I’d assume it works rather similar with v2.)

Comment: @CBroe A very quick grep through the source code doesn't yield anything like URL parsing.  There's no location.search, or even a location filter.  My solution below describes pretty much how it would work internally anyway.

Comment: @JohnGreen: The example they give on that site _implements_ exactly that with the help of BBQ.

Comment: @CBroe My bad.  I hadn't read it (or really, bothered to read it).  I assumed it was built-in functionality, which was missing.  Really, any hash monitor will work, from the stupidest/simplest one that I quickly drafted to more advanced ones like BBQ.  I'd never heard of BBQ before (and it seems dead, having not been updated in 5 years), though I've used others and rolled my own full stacks before -- this isn't a particularly hard problem to solve.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the BBQ link. It works. The only problem now is that the direct link: http://new-had.herrmanneasyeditdemo.com/#work=&filter=.law-firms does not scroll down to the "Work" section. Any idea how I could get this to work?

Comment: That I’m afraid you will have to implement yourself on top of that now … because your hash does not link to a valid target inside the document any more. You’d need to look at the hash yourself, see if there’s something in it it targets a valid id in your document, and then scroll there yourself … probably not only on the `hashchange` firing, but on initial page load as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could always format the link such that each filter is defined in the hash, then parse it out:

```
http://example.com/#filter|somekey 

$(document).ready(function(){
    if (location.hash.indexOf('#filter|') > -1)
    {
        $container.isotope({ filter: location.hash.substring(('#filter|').length)})
    }
});
```

Two caveats:
1).  If you're making a long page, you'll want to parse the hash and invoke that page navigation as well.  Otherwise, you'll be pointed at a nonexistant a-name.

2).  The document.ready might be a bit tricky.  You may want to defer it, or place it explicitly after the isotope loading code.